# Confusion regarding joblib.dump()

Tags: scikit-learn, joblib

One way to save sklearn models is to use `joblib.dump(model,filename)`. I have a confusion regarding the filename argument. One way to run this function is through :

```
joblib.dump(model,"model.joblib")
```

This saves the model successfully and also the model is loaded correctly using the:

```
model=joblib.load("model.joblib")
```

Another way is to use :

```
joblib.dump(model,"model")
```

With no ".joblib" extension this time. This also runs successfully and the model is loaded correctly using the:

```
model=joblib.load("model")
```

What confuses me is the file extension in the filename, Is there a certain file extension that I should use for saving the model? Or it is not necessary to use a file extension as I did above? If it is not necessary, then why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no file extension that "must" be used to serialize a model. You can specify the compression method by using one of the supported filename extensions (`.z`, `.gz`, `.bz2`, `.xz` or `.lzma`). By default `joblib` will use `zlib` to serialize objects.

Therefore you can use any file extension. However it is a good practice to use the library as the extension in order to know how to load it.

I name my serialized model `model.pickle` when I am using `pickle` library and `model.joblib` when I am using `joblib`.